# Erro: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Tags: php

Tenho uma classe do qual estou tentando pegar a Sessão dessa forma:

```
session_start();
class metodoClass{ 
    ....
    public $usuario = $_SESSION["Usuario"];
    ....
}
```

Porém quando faço isso, dá o erro: **Constant expression contains invalid operations**.

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não pesquisei a fundo, mas acredito que no momento de definição da classe a super global `$_SESSION` ainda não esteja disponível.

Você pode definir esse valor no momento de instanciação da classe:

```
<?php

session_start();

class metodoClass{ 

    public $usuario;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->usuario = $_SESSION["Usuario"];
    }

}
```

Veja [funcionando](https://3v4l.org/QX6Ea).

Comment: Obrigado gmsantos.